# Use WHERE + AND + CASE + IN when crafting T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that has a few variables that may or may not be passed. they are a list of PKs from other tables, so FKs but formatted in as a string of CSVs.

here's what the query essentially looks like

```
DECLARE @SomeIds VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
CREATE TABLE #TempIds (Id INT)

IF (@SomeIds = '' OR @SomeIds = NULL) INSERT INTO #TempIds VALUES (NULL)
ELSE INSERT INTO #TempIds SELECT * FROM SplitString(@SomeIds,',') -- SplitString() is a user function

SELECT cont.varchar_LastName AS LastName
      ,cred.varchar_CredentialName AS CredentialName
  FROM [dbo].[tbl_Contacts] AS cont
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_ContactsCredentials] AS cc ON cont.pk_int_Id = cc.fk_ContactId
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Credentials] AS cred ON cc.fk_CredentialId = cred.pk_int_Id
```

So this query basically gives me a full list of contacts both with and without a credential name. I don't have a WHERE clause, so not surprised.

I get data basically like:

```
LastName  |  CredentialName
---------------------------
Stevens   |  Admin
Arnolds   |  User
Bishop    |  NULL
Evans     |  NULL
```

So if I add a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE cred.pk_int_Id IN (SELECT * FROM #TempIds)
```

I get zero results.

When I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM #TempIds
```

I get this:

```
Id
-----------
NULL
```

When I run it with "real values" in `@SomeIds` like `'1,2'` then it works fine.

I presume this is because my WHERE clause is looking in the `cred` table and there are no `NULL` values in that table, so that's why I'm not getting anything.

But I'm not sure how I fix it?

I guess I really want to do something like this:

```
WHERE CredentialName IN (SELECT * FROM #TempIds)
```

But I believe to do that, I'd have to run the first query into another temp table, then run a second query on that table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what do you expect when `@SomeIds` is empty or null? The pk_int_Id that are NULL? Or maybe ignore the criteria on  pk_int_Id, getting everything?  Btw, can your Sql Server use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)?

Comment: i'd like to ignore the criteria entirely when `@SomeIds` is `NULL` or `''` but use the `IN` logic when it is NOT either of those...

Comment: Refer to [updated kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: Referring to columns from cred in the WHERE clause defeats the outer join as well - that converts both outer joins into inner joins.

Comment: @SMor -- that seems like a problem. is there a workaround? the kitchen sink thing looks amazing BTW. that's great, just lots of dynamic sql...

Comment: Have you considered passing the table as a Table Valued Parameter instead of a CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid a temp table

```
WHERE (NULLIF(@SomeIds,'') IS NULL OR cred.pk_int_Id IN (SELECT value FROM SplitString(@SomeIds,',')))
```

Or if your Sql Server version supports [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

```
WHERE (NULLIF(@SomeIds,'') IS NULL OR cred.pk_int_Id IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SomeIds,',')))
```

And then don't initialize `@SomeIds` to make it get all records.

Comment: i tried this, gives me no records, but runs successfully (no errors)

Comment: Yes, but try it without putting something in the variable.

Comment: ok, this looks like it might work. query is working, trying as a SP now...

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a `UNION` for this. Putting an `OR` in a `WHERE` clause can make for some bad execution plans, and often makes indexes unusable.

```
SELECT cont.varchar_LastName AS LastName
    ,cred.varchar_CredentialName AS CredentialName
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Contacts] AS cont
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_ContactsCredentials] AS cc
    ON cont.pk_int_Id = cc.fk_ContactId
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Credentials] AS cred
    ON cc.fk_CredentialId = cred.pk_int_Id
WHERE cred.pk_int_Id IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SomeIds,','))

UNION ALL

SELECT cont.varchar_LastName AS LastName
    ,cred.varchar_CredentialName AS CredentialName
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Contacts] AS cont
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_ContactsCredentials] AS cc
    ON cont.pk_int_Id = cc.fk_ContactId
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Credentials] AS cred
    ON cc.fk_CredentialId = cred.pk_int_Id
WHERE NULLIF(@SomeIds,'') IS NULL
```

I talk about using `OR` in `UPDATES` statements [here](https://brendan-mccaffrey.com/2021/12/20/stop-using-the-or-operator/). But the same logic applies to `SELECT`.